# XPath to select XML node without a child node with a certain value?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<targets>
    <target sanctions-set-id="4387" ssid="5762">
        <individual>
            <identity ssid="5764" main="true">
                <name ssid="27036" name-type="primary-name">
                    <value>SomeName1</value>
                </name>
            </identity>
        </individual>
        <modification modification-type="de-listed" enactment-date="2016-02-29" publication-date="2016-03-01" effective-date="2016-03-01"/>
        <modification modification-type="amended" enactment-date="2015-11-17" publication-date="2015-11-18" effective-date="2015-11-18"/>
        <modification modification-type="amended" enactment-date="2014-11-27" publication-date="2014-11-28" effective-date="2014-11-28"/>
        <modification modification-type="amended" enactment-date="2013-12-18" publication-date="2013-12-19" effective-date="2013-12-20"/>
        <modification modification-type="listed"/>
    </target>
    <target sanctions-set-id="4388" ssid="5763">
        <individual>
            <identity ssid="5765" main="true">
                <name ssid="27037" name-type="primary-name">
                    <value>SomeName2</value>
                </name>
            </identity>
        </individual>
        <modification modification-type="amended" enactment-date="2015-11-17" publication-date="2015-11-18" effective-date="2015-11-18"/>
        <modification modification-type="amended" enactment-date="2014-11-27" publication-date="2014-11-28" effective-date="2014-11-28"/>
        <modification modification-type="amended" enactment-date="2013-12-18" publication-date="2013-12-19" effective-date="2013-12-20"/>
        <modification modification-type="listed"/>
    </target>   
</targets>
```

I need to select any target node that does not have a child node of modification-type delisted.  In other words, my xpath should only return the second target of SomeName2 because there is no delisted modification-type.

This is the closest I've been able to get, but it still selects both.

```
targets/target[modification[@modification-type != 'de-listed']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your XPath is selecting both is because both do have `modification` elements with `@modification-type` attribute equal to values other than `de-listed`. Use `not()` instead of `!=`...

This XPath,

```
//target[not(modification[@modification-type = 'de-listed'])]
```

will select all `target` elements with **no** `modification` children with `modification-type` attributes equal to `de-listed`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks.